# Make text into a link in OmniGraffle

Tags: macos, url, links, omnigraffle

If I have an object, such as a circle or rectangle, with a label (text inside), how can I make turn a word of that text into link, a hypertext web link with a backing URL?

For example, within the OmniGraffle app or an exported PDF, in the object shown below I want to be able to click on the word *JDK* and have my web browser open to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the “Pro” edition of OmniGraffle, then linking to a box or other drawing object is the easy thing to do. It's not a true link to text like you asked, but maybe a small object surrounding the text would be worth the hassle.

Now on to the easy option:

- Select any object / shape that exists in the canvas/layers picker (or is visibly selectable).
- Select the inspector control if the right inspector pane is not visible (click on the circle with an i in it)
- Select Properties (the blue gear below)

[image: Graffle inspector window - object properties]

- Open the action triangle (if needed) and select **@ Open a URL** and paste in the link you wish to have linked

[image].

Comment: I don't see the Action inspector in my OmniGraffle 7.11.5, Standard edition, although I do have the menu View > Actions (which doesn't reveal anything - presumably because I don't have any actions in my canvas). Manual states the "Action Browse Tool" is a Pro feature, so presumably this isn't possible in Standard edition.

Comment: Well done @Ashley that made an excellent edit to the answer. Appreciate the help on the feature cost and availability.

Comment: i could include the link in the Action field, and from within Omnigraffle it works also, but not from a generated png ( using 7.2 Pro ).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using OmniFocus Standard edition (version 7.11.5), where the Action feature described in another answer doesn't seem to exist.

However, it does seem possible to create text with hyperlinks in another application, then copy and paste that into a text box in OmniGraffle.

For example:

1. In Pages (I'm using version 7.1), type some text - eg a paragraph, where you want one word to be a link.
2. Select some of the text, where you want to add a hyperlink.
3. Use the menu Format > Add Link > Webpage (or right click the selected text and use Add Link > Webpage there, or press cmd-k).
4. Configure the link destination.
5. Select the paragraph and use Edit > Copy.
6. In OmniGraffle, use Edit > Paste.